# EWS API: Anything I call update_item for a meeting, it ends up canceling the meeting for any attendees

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm using the EWS API (targeting Exchange 2010) I cannot figure out why anything I make a request to update a calendar meeting/item. Is there something I'm missing or is this the expected behavior? I'm able to make a change from Outlook to the meeting without it sending out a cancellation email to all attendees except the organizer.

The below is a sample of the relevant portion of the SOAP request. I replaced the actual attendee's email addresses, item ID and change key.

`{:send_meeting_invitations_or_cancellations=>"SendOnlyToChanged",:conflict_resolution=>"AutoResolve", :item_changes=>[{:updates=>[{:set_item_field=>{:field_uRI=>{:field_uRI=>"item:Subject"},
    :calendar_item=>{:sub_elements=>[{:subject=>{:text=>"Thursday 11AM Recurring"}}]}}},
    {:set_item_field=>{:field_uRI=>{:field_uRI=>"item:Body"},  :calendar_item=>{:sub_elements=>[{:body=>{"BodyType"=>"HTML", :text=>"HI"}}]}}},
    {:set_item_field=>{:field_uRI=>{:field_uRI=>"calendar:Location"},:calendar_item=>{:sub_elements=>[{:location=>{:text=>"LA, CA"}}]}}},
    {:set_item_field=>{:field_uRI=>{:field_uRI=>"calendar:Start"}, :calendar_item=>{:sub_elements=>[{:start=>{:text=>"2019-03-07T19:00:00.0000000"}}]}}},
    {:set_item_field=>{:field_uRI=>{:field_uRI=>"calendar:StartTimeZone"}, :calendar_item=>{:sub_elements=>[{:start_time_zone=>{"Id"=>"UTC"}}]}}},
    {:set_item_field=>{:field_uRI=>{:field_uRI=>"calendar:End"}, :calendar_item=>{:sub_elements=>[{:end=>{:text=>"2019-03-07T19:30:00.0000000"}}]}}},
    {:set_item_field=>{:field_uRI=>{:field_uRI=>"calendar:EndTimeZone"},:calendar_item=>{:sub_elements=>[{:end_time_zone=>{"Id"=>"UTC"}}]}}},
    {:set_item_field=>{:field_uRI=>{:field_uRI=>"calendar:RequiredAttendees"},:calendar_item=>{:sub_elements=>[{:required_attendees=>{:sub_elements=>[
    {:mailbox=>{:name=>"Joe ABC",:email_address=>"joe@abc.com", :routing_Type=>"SMTP"}},
    {:mailbox=>{:name=>"John ABC", :email_address=>"john@abc.com",:routing_Type=>"SMTP"}}]}}]}}}],
    :item_id=>{:id=>"AAMkAGJjNWIzNzI2LTM1N2YtNDVkMi05NzU5LTRj",
    :change_key=>"DwAAABYAAADWK9s0Y5iSSLP"}}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Set_Item_Field to update the required attendees this will overwrite the current property so if any attendees aren't in the updated collection your effectively canceling the meeting for those attendees. If you want to use Set_Item_Field to update attendees then you need to include all the attendees for that type because your replacing the collection for the recipient type not appending to it.

Comment: Thanks Glen. Do you know if it has to be the exact values for name and email for Exchange to not send out a cancelation notice? I ask because I tried sending the same email and its seems to think it is a new attendee, meaning it cancels and then readds the meeting in Outlook.

Comment: You should be doing a Get first to get the collection then append to it you can't be wrong then.

Comment: I do get a GET first which is why this is so puzzling. I've tried to use the same except attendee names/emails with same casing as well (verified this through examine the raw soap request) and it still cancels the event first.

Comment: Something doesn't sound correct then I would suggest you post the XML you using the above is hard to read and not the actually request that is being sent to the server. Its also missing the Message disposition which might be you problem

Comment: Glen, thanks for your time! As I was doing another check to see compare the XML being sent, I noticed the issue in my XML structure was incorrect!